# Validar datos cuando se requiera en cakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp

llevo una semana con esta situación y no encuentro información sobre el tema, sucede lo siguiente, tengo un formulario que tiene controles que se muestran cuando se le requiera, por ejemplo, mi aplicación registra un partido entre dos jugadores y dependiendo de la modalidad del juego aparecerán algunos controles y otros no, el caso es que necesito validar esos campos cuando la modalidad lo requiera, un ejemplo más detallado, se va a registrar una partida de billar carambola, la modalidad requiere registrar las tacadas y los puntos de cada jugador, aquí en este caso sí necesito que me valide esos campos, si la modalidad es billar bola 8 no se requiere registrar tacadas y puntos, entonces no quiero que me los valide, en mi Model tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function validationDefaul(Validator $validator) {
  //Otras reglas

    $validator      
        ->add('tacadas',['requireTacadas' => ['rule' => 'requireTacada','provider' => 'table', 'message' => 'Requerido.']])     
        ->add('tacadas','valid',['rule' => 'numeric', 'message' => 'Debe ser un valor numérico.'])
        ->allowEmpty(true);      

  return $validator;
}
```

La función requireTacadas es la siguiente:

```
function requireTacadas($value,$context) {

    if($context["data"]["modal_cushion_point"] && empty($context["data"]["tacadas"])) {
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true; 
    }
```

Cuando la modalidad requiere anotarse las tacadas y el usuario lo deja en blanco me muestra el texto "This field cannot be left empty" en vez del "Requerido", si la modalidad no requiere anotar las tacadas como el billar bola 8 y los controles no están visibles no me permite guardar la partida porque sigue validandola como vacío, en mi plantilla he intentado ponerle required a false de los controles y aún así las valida como vacío y que es obligatorio, cabe destacar que en la BD los campos permiten datos nulos.

Uso CakePHP 3.5

Comment: modifiqué `->allowEmpty(true)` a `->allowEmpty('tacadas', true)` ahora no me muestra ningún texto y no valida mi función requireTacadas.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución a mi problema, y es que hay que hacer uso del evento beforeValidate(), en el modelo ponemos la regla de validación de ésta forma

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {

    $validator
    ->add('tacadas','valid',['rule' => 'numeric', 'message' => 'Debe ser un valor numérico.'])
    ->notEmpty('tacadas','Requerido');

    return $validator;

}
```

OJO remover el uso de requirePresence porque automáticamente valida todo el tiempo como un campo requerido, en el evento beforeValidate hacemos lo siguiente:

```
public function beforeValidate(){
    if(!$this->data["Partidos"]["modal_cushion_point"]) {
        unset($this->data["Partidos"]["tacadas"]);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false; //es requerido
    }
}
```

Y listo, podemos campos cuando se le requieran.

Saludos.